# How to validate "multi header"?

Tags: rest-assured

I have a JAX-RS service that returns multiple "Link" headers:

```
Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
Link=http://localhost:7080/rest/resource?ps=2&category=service&page=2; rel='next'
Link=http://localhost:7080/rest/resource?page=1&ps=2&category=service; rel='current'
Content-Encoding=gzip
```

Now I want to validate that there is a link with rel=next and another with rel=current, but none with rel=prev

When I write

```
expect()
.header("Link", containsString("page=2"))
.header("Link", containsString("current"))
.header("Link", not(containsString("prev")))
```

Then rest-assured fails on the 2nd line, as the 1st Link header line from above does not contain 'current'

What is the right way to run those checks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in that way unfortunately (because REST Assured returns only the first header value). A workaround would be:

```
List<Header> listHeaders = get("/your_resource").headers().getList("Link");
```

Now you can assert each header value using using normal JUnit asserts (or something similar).